# Why doesn't RabbitMQ need a schema registry, when Kafka needs it?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq

If Kafka needs, because there may be a lot of messages in the queue. The same can happen to Rabbit if you don’t read it.

Required this registry for Kafka, if you are using Arvo or Protobuf. So, the Java class can be generated from Arvo or Protobuf and you can send the byte array view into Kafka.
Rabbit perspective: if I use Protobuf or Arvo and this class sends into Rabbit, why not need a schema registry?

I understand what difference between RabbitMQ and Kafka, just I do not understand the existence of a schema registry. Why doesn’t one need it while the other does?

**Question #1:** Why can not Kafka work without Schema Registry, and Rabbit why can work?

**Question #2:** If a rabbit does not need a schema registry, how can skipping the schema registry be done in the case of Kafka?

**Question #3:** How can I use Schema Registry for RabbitMQ?

Comment: Apache kafka does not require messages to follow a schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka doesn't require it, and there's nothing preventing you from serializing your own byte arrays with a schema registry client before sending/after consuming from any other message queue.

The benefit of the Registry is for allowing compatibility between decoupled clients , not a limitation or requirement of the message queue server.

Confluent Server can be configured to do server-side record validation against the registry, but this isn't a feature of Apache Kafka itself

> how can skipping the schema registry be done in the case of Kafka?

The producers aren't forced to use any particular format. Everything is sent and stored as bytes